# Inverse functions using complex numbers

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Recently I came across a method to find the inverse function, in which if we assume $z=x+iy$ we can say that the inverse of $y=f(x)$ is $iz^*$

However, when I try to find the functions when a function is equal to its inverse, $z=iz^*$ and expand it, I get only the case where the real and imaginary part of z is same , i.e, $y=x$ Why am I missing out on the other clear solution $y=1/x?$

Also are there any other solutions to this equation?

PS:By $z^*$,  I mean the complex conjugate of z.

Comment: There are infinitely many functions which are their own inverse, for example $$f(x)=(3-x^3)^{\frac13}$$

Comment: Any good reason for puting each and every mathematical expression within a pair of `$$`'s. In many cases a pair of `$`'s will be enough.

Comment: I am new to mathjax.... Will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ you are associating the complex graph $\Gamma_f=\left\{\,x+\mathrm i y\,|\,f(x)=y\,\right\}\subset\mathbb C$. Since $\mathrm i(x+\mathrm i y)^* = y+\mathrm i x$, this allows us to obtain the graph of the inverse of an invertible $f$ as
$$
\Gamma_{f^{-1}} = \left\{\, \mathrm iz^*\,|\, z\in\Gamma_f\,\right\}.
$$
Now a function is its own inverse $f=f^{-1}$ if and only if $\Gamma_f = \Gamma_{f^{-1}}$.

The equation you wrote down is a lot stronger: asking that $z=\mathrm i z^*$ for $z\in\Gamma_f$ is equivalent to $x+\mathrm i y=y+\mathrm i x$, so that $f$ can only be given by $f(x)=x$.

The correct condition for $f$ being its own inverse would be that for all $z\in \mathbb C$ we have
$$
z\in \Gamma_f \,\Longleftrightarrow\, \mathrm i z^* \in \Gamma_f.
$$
So $z$ and $\mathrm i z^*$ don't need to be equal, they just need to be either both on the graph or both not on the graph for any $z\in\mathbb C$.

Here's a simple example: Consider $f(x)=-x$ so that $\Gamma_f$ consists of all $z=x-\mathrm i x$. These *do not* satisfy $z=\mathrm i z^*$, but they *do* satisfy
$$
\mathrm i z^* = -x+\mathrm i x = (-x) - \mathrm i (-x) \in \Gamma_f.
$$

Comment: Will you please be kind enough to provide another example so I can understand this better? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Phy_Amatuer There's one in the comments of your question. Try to work with that!